# Definite integral gives solution involving Pi, is this result exact?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Mathematica novice here. When I compute the integral

```
Integrate[ Sin[x] Sin[3*x] Cos[2*y] / (Sin[x] ^2 + Cos [y]^2) , {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

I receive the output
$$ \frac{\pi}{2} (\pi - 4)$$

Does the fact that the output is a function of `Pi` (instead of, say, $-1.3484...$) mean that `NIntegrate` was not used, and the result was computed exactly?

And if so, is there a way of receiving a "step by step" computation?
`WolframAlpha["Integrate[ Sin[x] Sin[3*x] Cos[2*y] / (Sin[x] ^2 + Cos [y]^2) , {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]"` fails to understand the query...

Comment: With exact inputs, where there are no decimal numbers involved anywhere, you get exact outputs. Integrate uses very powerful methods that do not usually have any steps that an ordinary user can ever understand. There is a free add-on package https://rulebasedintegration.org/ that you can install and there is an option for it to show the steps that it used. BUT it ONLY does indefinite integrals, and not definite integrals. You might be able to study the result and see if it is valid to then substitute in the bounds to get a definite integral result. All this will take some study to understand

Comment: `WolframAlpha["integrate Sin[x] Sin[3*x] Cos[2*y]/(Sin[x]^2+Cos[y]^2) from x=0 to pi from y=0 to pi"]` provides a numeric result, `-1.34838` which is consistent with the analytic result.